# No platform plugin, neither libqtforandroid.so or libqtforandroidGL.so, included in package. Please include one. in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, android, qt5

I installed qt 5.15.2 a few hours ago using qt-unified-linux-x64-4.6.0-online.run on ubuntu 22.04. All packages are installed and configured using JDK 17, sdk and ndk 25.1, 22.1, 21.3(automatically installed when updated from device settings in qt) and I think it is okay. No error shows. But I have created a simple widget app and want to access the Android Intent. So I have added androidextras in . pro file and i get this error message "```

```
:-1: error: No platform plugin, neither libqtforandroid.so or libqtforandroidGL.so, included in package. Please include one.
```

I don't understand where is the problem. Here are my project details:

```
QT += core gui androidextras

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17
You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
In order to do so, uncomment the following line.

#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000 # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES +=
main.cpp
widget.cpp

HEADERS +=
widget.h

FORMS +=
widget.ui
Default rules for deployment.

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QAndroidIntent>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
~Widget();

private:
Ui::Widget *ui;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

I have checked and installed llvm like this:

```
$    llvm-config --version
14.0.0
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to mix qt5 with qt4:  `qt 5.15.2`  using `qt-unified-linux-x64-4.6.0-online.run` . Can't work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So what should I do? Which version of the installer should I use for qt 5.15.2 or the latest?

Comment: I have downloaded it from this link https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer-oss?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.qt.io%2F. There is no other selection option I found.

Comment: I do not understand what your'e trying to achieve, but usually you do not download software from some page - like in windows. You open your "Software Center" and install the packages you need - that is similar to installing an app on android.

Comment: should I use qt-unified-linux-x64-4.5.2-online.run?  I want to install a custom location I will select. so that I can use it in the future for system crashes.  How can I do it?

Comment: I need to access the Android module not matter it is qt 5.15 or qt 6.6. I read Androidextras is deprecated is there any way to access it in qt 6.6 or the latest in different name?

Comment: You did not provide any infos about what your are trying to do. So do not expect answers. You would to have sit down an explain - in length - what your are trying to do. Not in the comments -but in your question. Since you do not provide any information I 'd vote to close your question.